# How to Sort multidimensional array by value in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Hi I need to Sort the multi dimensional array by its value  My array is like this I need to group the array by its position to create a new array sorting is just confusing How do i create a sorted array from this

```
Array
(
[prodata] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [position] => 3
                    [products] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 227
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [position] => 4
                    [products] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 441
                            [1] => 54
                        )

                )

        )
[richtext] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [position] => 1
                    [header] => qwewqe
                    [content] => contentadaqsdas
)
)

)
```

I this array i need to sort by it position and create a new array,

Goal

```
Array
(
[0]=>Array(
[richtext] => Array
        (

        [position] => 1
        [header] => qwewqe
        [content] => contentadaqsdas            

)

)
[1]=>Array(
    [prodata] => Array
        (

        [position] => 3
        [products] => Array
            (
                [0] => 227
            )       

)

)
[2]=>Array(
    [prodata] => Array
        (

        [position] => 4
        [products] => Array
            (
                [0] => 441
                [1] => 54
            )       

)

)

)
```

How do I achieve this help

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Did you try anything? usort?

Comment: I tried to create new array in for each but not worth

Comment: $keys = array_column($myarray, '0');  
array_multisort($keys, SORT_ASC, $myarray);  try this, i use this for similar problems

Comment: Can you provide us with the PHP array input?

Comment: did you mean form input array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flat the multi dimension array first, then sort it. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/LBI86)

```
$flat_array = [];
foreach($multi_dimension_array as $k => $array){
    foreach($array as $value){
        $flat_array[] = array(
            $k => $value
        );
    }
}
usort($flat_array,function($a,$b){return current($a)["position"] - current($b)["position"];});

print_r($flat_array);
```

Though this code works, **But I suggest restruct the data source for better data format. Which can make it a easy work**